# Refresh background view when dismissing sheet segue

Tags: macos, swift3, segue, viewdidappear

I'm looking for a way to attempt to refresh the background view of my macOS app when dismissing a view that was segued to using the sheet segue. Currently, I have debug code saying if a viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad are triggered in the main view, but they are not triggering when closing the segued view. The only way I can get the view to refresh is by performing another segue back, which creates a strange double sheet animation.

Is there any way to get the view to refresh when dismissing the segued view that is in the same window as the main view?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using NotificationCenter

In my mainVC

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.viewDidAppear()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.viewDidAppear), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loadView"), object: nil)
}
```

In my secondVC

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loadView"), object: nil)
```